# Node.js and Zaproxy UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Error: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, owasp, zap

```
var zapClient = require('zaproxy');

const zapOptions = {
  key : 'abcdefghijklmn',
  proxy : 'http://localhost:8090/'
};

const zaproxy = new zapClient(zapOptions);

zaproxy.spider.scan("https://www.google.co.in");
```

i am trying to run above code i am getting :
(node:8380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Error: socket hang up error.

i have tried [socket hang up error with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207333/socket-hang-up-error-with-nodejs) and ["Request error: Socket hang up" with nodeJS on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564350/request-error-socket-hang-up-with-nodejs-on-amazon-ec2?rq=1) didn't help.

Comment: What happens if you delete the last line of your code, then run it?  Do you still get the error?

Comment: if i remove last line it works fine

Comment: Can you post a link to the source where you got `zaproxy.spider.scan` ?  After quickly glancing at the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zaproxy) for zaproxy, I didn't see that method used.  the `.scan` part might be depreciated or meant to be used in a different way.

Comment: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiGen_spider

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing the last line of your code to this should fix the problem:

```
zaproxy.spider.scan("https://www.google.co.in", (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    //do something with res here
});

//can't do anything with res here
```

Comment: still the problem persist the same.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the zap.log file - that might be logging errors which by default are not reported to the client (for security reasons - this can be disabled for testing)